# Need help generating three address code witth lex and yacc

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am generating three address code for a c like program containing declaration,arithmetic,boolean, if and while statements. 
Currently i am beginning with arithmetic expression. I am reading the c like program from a text file.

**Lex code:**

[parser.lex](http://pastebin.com/4ytPrmjm)

**Yacc code:**

[parser.yacc](http://pastebin.com/8vdSJnjE)

**Input C like program(contents of test.txt)**

```
a=1+2/3;
```

I have a make file like:

```
bison -d -v parser.y
flex  -o parser.lex.c parser.lex
gcc  -o cparser parser.lex.c parser.tab.c -lfl -lm 
./cparser
```

When i compile my input file, i get the following output:

```
t1=2/3/3
t2=1+2/3;+t1
a=1+2/3;=t2
Parsing Successful. The three address code is: 
syntax error
Successful parsing.
```

- Why are the $1 $2 $3...etc not containing the desired reduction?
- Why is the stderr printing syntax error?

Comment: For one, yyparse() returns a value of 0 if the input it parses is valid, you a getting a 1 return so the "Successful parsing" message is wrong. The "syntax error" message is coming from yyerror() as expected. I can't speak to the other issues, I haven't studied the grammar.

Comment: Careful of tagging; flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer; flex is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your lexer code, you have things like:

```
{number} {yylval=yytext; return NUMBER;}
```

this will set `$$` for that token to point at the lexer internal buffer which will be clobbered by the next call to yylex, so when you go to print it in the parser, you'll print some garbage.  You need something like:

```
{number} {yylval=strdup(yytext); return NUMBER;}
```

In addition, you have patterns like:

```
'int' return INT;
```

The `'` character is not special in any way to flex, so this pattern matches the 5-character sequence `'int'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (yyparse())
```

should be

```
  if (yyparse() == 0)
```

In your lex rule `"\n" {/*simply skip new line*/}` you could keep track of the line number so when there is a syntax error you can print out the line number.

Comment: I took care of it. But why is the three address code not being generated correctly?